# Serious Wi-Fi network issue on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless, internet, 17.04

I have a serious issue after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04.

My machine is connected to wifi and IP address is obtained. But there is no internet connection.

Everything was working fine before the upgrade.

In `/var/log/syslog` I can see many `DNSSEC validation failed` messages.

I tried this, but did NOT help:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Then restart network-manager

Comment: Could be this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1650927.

Comment: Thank you for the bug report. It would be great if someone can suggest me a solution. Anyway I do not kow how to install the bugfix later because there is no internet connection on my laptop...

Comment: Could be related: https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3259-1/. Update is available. @zappee Nothing works like a cable.

Comment: How to install any fix without internet connection?

Comment: I just swapped my ralink usb for a realtek usb, and everything came to life!
All I had to do was re-enter my wi-fi passcode.

Comment: And everyting was working untill the upgrade!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link of the [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1681513).

And here is what you should try:

Open a terminal and type or paste this and run it:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Then edit the file and add these lines to the bottom of the file:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Save the file and run this command in a terminal:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

***EDIT:***
Sorry, just read your edit to your question.

Try this line of code(it fixed my internet in 16.10 and 17.04:

```
sudo killall dnsmasq
```

Answer (score 4):

As written [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905543/ubuntu-17-04-weird-dns-issue), create the file /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/no-dnssec.conf with the following content:

```
[Resolve]
DNSSEC=no
```

And restart. I tried the scan-rand-mac-address thing and adding 8.8.8.8 as DNS, but that was the only thing that worked for me.