# Serious Wi-Fi network issue on Ubuntu 17.04, part 2

Tags: wireless, internet, dns, 17.04

After upgrading my ubuntu to 17.04 I am not able to connect to internet. I asked your help and I got a nice response which helped me.

This is my previous question: [Serious wifi network issue on ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905997/serious-wifi-network-issue-on-ubuntu-17-04)

Everything was working fine yesterday but now I have the same issue. My laptop connects to the Wi-Fi but there is no internet connection. I can see again there are tons of DNSSEC errors in syslog.

It makes me crazy. That is a really serious issue. Please help me, I must to use Internet.

Comment: Please tell us the result of: `ls  /etc/systemd/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network manager is having trouble resolving DNS servers for now in Ubuntu 17.04, you can work around it by adding the google DNS servers in network manager which are usually faster then your own ISP servers in many cases.

Add the google nameservers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in "IPv4-settings" in the network-manager at the top right of the screen.

Right-click->Edit connections->choose your wifi connection->Edit->IPV4-settings> Change to "Automatic (DHCP), addresses only" and add the nameservers in the field "DNS-servers", then go to IPV6 settings and set to ignore, then save.

Restart the network by doing:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

or reboot your computer.
[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems that solution works fine. When there is no internet connection on my laptop even I can ping google DNS servers ;) This setting should be okay. Let's wait for 2 days. Thank you a lot!